# HTML / CSS : Creating and positionning 5 blocs

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am trying to positionning 5 blocs in my page.

I would like to have 3 columns in fact :

- First column : Two blocs (Favorites and meetings)
- Second column : (recents news and tweets)
- Third column : Other favorites column

Like this :

[image]

But i have a problem for positionning the third column.

Here is my HTML code :

```
<div class="containerBloc" >
    <div class="box-1">
        <div class="box-menu"><img src="src/ui_dashboard/img/ic_action_users.png" id="imgIntoMenu"><span id="textMenu">Favorites</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-2">
        <div class="box-menu"><img src="src/ui_dashboard/img/ic_action_feed.png" id="imgIntoMenu"><span id="textMenu">Recent news</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-5">
        <div class="box-menu"><img src="src/ui_dashboard/img/ic_action_users.png" id="imgIntoMenu"><span id="textMenu">Favorites</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-3">
        <div class="box-menu"><img src="src/ui_dashboard/img/ic_action_calendar_month.png" id="imgIntoMenu"><span id="textMenu">Upcoming meetings</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-4">
        <div class="box-menu"><img src="src/ui_dashboard/img/ic_action_twitter.png" id="imgIntoMenu"><span id="textMenu">Tweets de</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS :

```
.containerBloc {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 150px;
}
.box-1, .box-2, .box-3, .box-4 {
    float: left;
    margin: 1%;
    min-height: 150px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #B0B0B0;
}
.box-1, .box-2 {
    height: 200px;
}
.box-1, .box-3 {
    width: 30%;
}
.box-2, .box-4 {
    width: 60%;
}
.box-5 {
    margin: 1%;
    min-height: 150px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #B0B0B0;
    float : right;
    height : 100%;
    width : 40%;
}

.box-menu {
    background-color: #EFEFEF ;
    height : 40px;
    color : #B0B0B0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #B0B0B0;
}

#imgIntoMenu {
    margin-left : 10px;
    margin-top : 4px;
}

#textMenu {
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 13px;
}
```

My complete code is here : http://jsfiddle.net/mzV85/

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: If you're going to work with columns, why don't you create `div`s for them?

Comment: What's the problem with the third block? You need to add more details so we can help

Comment: You should be using ids in place of the classes.

Comment: Anyone take this. http://jsfiddle.net/mzV85/1/ I'm going home

Comment: @SurjithSM : go home...take a a good rest and come back tomorrow,then understand that you are not supposed to change the HTML markup....then solve it!

Comment: @NoobEditor lol this dude definitely just re-wrote his code to make it work.  thats somethin i'd go n do dammit he took my move

Comment: @Deryck : yeah...but this kind of manipulated solution giving thing really pisses me off!!

Comment: I know it's kinda like we're a freelance programming site that doesn't get paid lol

Comment: @Deryck : agreed but then too it has to have a standard....why break a code pattern and then manipulate it just to show that you can solve it in whatever way u wish, not considering what OP wants!! X(

Comment: @mayanksingh Wow.. Big Conv. overnight. Did OP mentioned he can't change the HTML? I feel Its good to find a best solution rather than doing CSS hacks.

Answer (score 2):

This **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mzV85/6/)** should get you going.there is some tydying up to do in the CSS code.

The point is to Use Divs to wrap your columns. To set there added widths to 100% and to float them to the left.

HTML:

```
<div class="containerBloc">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="box-1">
            <div class="box-menu">
                <img src="src/ui_dashboard/img/ic_action_users.png" id="imgIntoMenu" /> <span id="textMenu">Favorites</span>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box-2">
            <div class="box-menu">
                <img src="src/ui_dashboard/img/ic_action_feed.png" id="imgIntoMenu" /> <span id="textMenu">Recent news</span>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="box-3">
            <div class="box-menu">
                <img src="src/ui_dashboard/img/ic_action_calendar_month.png" id="imgIntoMenu" /><span id="textMenu">Upcoming meetings</span>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box-4">
            <div class="box-menu">
                <img src="src/ui_dashboard/img/ic_action_twitter.png" id="imgIntoMenu" /><span id="textMenu">Tweets de @__Erwan</span>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="box-5">
            <div class="box-menu">
                <img src="src/ui_dashboard/img/ic_action_users.png" id="imgIntoMenu" /><span id="textMenu">Favorites</span>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.col{
    float:left;
    width:33%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.containerBloc {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 150px;
}
.box-1, .box-2, .box-3, .box-4 {
    margin: 1%;
    min-height: 150px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #B0B0B0;
}
.box-1, .box-2 {
    height: 200px;
}
.box-1, .box-3 {
    width: 98%;
}
.box-2, .box-4 {
    width: 98%;
}
.box-5 {
    margin: 1%;
    min-height: 150px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #B0B0B0;
    float : right;
    height : 100%;
    width : 98%;
}
.box-menu {
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    height : 40px;
    color : #B0B0B0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #B0B0B0;
}
#imgIntoMenu {
    margin-left : 10px;
    margin-top : 4px;
}
#textMenu {
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 13px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. How can i do in order to have a third column on the same height of others columns ?

Comment: It depends on your layout, If your columns have fixed height, then it is simple with CSS if not then JS can be needed.

Answer (score 1):

You should really be using a responsive grid system like Bootstrap.

However if I understand correctly you're just wanting to put together a three column layout, like this - http://jsfiddle.net/webbymatt/ngxA6/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="child">
        Favourites
    </div>
    <div class="child clearfix">
        Meetings
    </div>
  </div>

   <div class="col-2">
    <div class="child">
        Recent
    </div>
    <div class="child clearfix">
        Tweets
    </div>
  </div>

   <div class="col-3">
    <div class="child">
        Favourites
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The layout is breaking because the percentage widths you are using add up to more than 100%. If you reduce the width of your columns it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/mzV85/15/

CSS:

```
.box-1, .box-3 {
    width: 25%;
}
.box-2, .box-4 {
    width: 50%;
}
.box-5 {
    width : 19%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have Done a fiddle. Please check http://jsfiddle.net/mzV85/21/ . Please check the `width` of the containers properly.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem** : your markup has `box-1`, `box-2` and `box-5` in one line.....calculate their combined width and it comes > 100%; that's why your third box is not aligning

**see this demo**  http://jsfiddle.net/mzV85/10/  (*aligned the box in one line,not did the complete designing*)

```
.box-1, .box-2 {
    height: 200px;
    width:20%; /* do some changes here */
}
.box-1, .box-3 {
    width: 30%;/* do some changes here */
}
```

Play around with the width and *you will get it in one line* when its **combined width <=100%**